# Spotify API Illegal redirect_uri

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, spotify, clientid

I'm trying to progress through the Spotify developer API tutorial but when I try to access the user login page I get this error. I've triple checked that the URI in the code matches the one on MyApplications page but it still won't work. 
Here's the script,

```
var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var client_id = id;
var client_secret = secret;
var redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8888/callback";
```

[Image of error code and MyApplications page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEzeo.png)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I've been going over it for hours now, can someone help?

Answer (score 12):

You need your redirect URIs to be *exactly* the same. The URI you have registered in the Dashboard is http://localhost:8888/callback/ with a trailing slash. The version you use in your code does not have the trailing slash. Just change your redirect_uri to be:

```
var redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8888/callback/";
```

You can verify that this works with this example authorize URL I made: https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?client_id=df5c5a57b94a4817ae3ac4760c701983&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8888%2Fcallback%2F&scope=streaming%20user-read-birthdate%20user-read-private%20user-modify-playback-state&response_type=token&show_dialog=true

Comment: INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI

Comment: You can check it like that:
https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?client_id=[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[YOUR_REDIRECT_URI]&response_type=token&show_dialog=true

Just replace [YOUR_CLIENT_ID] and [YOUR_REDIRECT_URI], then it should work.

Answer (score 5):

I just needed to restart my Node server!

Steps to fix:

1. Ensure your redirect_uri has a trailing slash after `callback`. 
    Mine is: `http://localhost:8888/callback/`
2. Ensure your project in your [dashboard](https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications) has the **EXACT** same URL as the one in step 1 under the 'redirect URI' section. Make sure to press the green 'ADD' button to the right and the 'SAVE' button at the bottom.
3. Save your file and **RESTART YOUR NODE SERVER**. this may seem trivial. But took me 30 minutes until I finally tried restarting it.