# Is there another reason for Illegal redirect_URI error when using Spotify API?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to use the Spotify API (using Spotipy), however I am having issues with the authentication step.  I am following along a youtube [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vipVEWe86Lg&list=PLqgOPibB_QnzzcaOFYmY2cQjs35y0is9N&index=4) to learn it.  To do that, I am just following along with the code that is shown below.  However, when it opens into my web browser for authentication, I get an "Illegal redirect_uri" error.

I tried searching the web and came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418717/spotify-api-illegal-redirect-uri) that says that it is probably a typo in the redirect_URI on the spotify website or that has been set in my environment variable, however, I have quadruple checked to make sure there was no typo.  An image is attached that shows what my environment variable is and what the redirect_URI is set as in spotify.

Is there another reason that I could be getting this error?

Thank you for the help. [Spotify Redirect_URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZA7f.png)

```
import os
import sys
import json
import spotipy
import webbrowser
import spotipy.util as util
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError

#Get the username from terminal
username = sys.argv[1]

# Erase cache and prompt for user permission

try:
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username)
except:
    os.remove(f".cache-{username}")
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username)

#Create our spotifyObject
spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a security issue, since google.com will not understand the parameters of the request sent by the Spotify API. It looks like you are not trying to intercept the request (since you are using google.com), so you could try to use https://localhost:8080/ as the redirect url. Since there is (probably) no server running locally, no page will open (and you will get an error), but you only need to copy the url in the address bar ;-)